# Is there a way to get HotKey ID in OnHotKey function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm dealing with HotKeys in MFC. The way I'm registering HotKey is call `RegisterHotKey()` and declar a `OnHotKey` function in the header. At the end, I manually add that function to my Message Map

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CforkDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_INIT, &CforkDlg::OnBnClickedButtonInit)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_SPEED, &CforkDlg::OnBnClickedBtnSpeed)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHK_AUTOPICKUP, &CforkDlg::OnBnClickedChkAutopickup)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_HOTKEY, OnHotKey)//Hot Key handle function
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

However, the OnHotKey function only takes in 2 parameters. One is the modifiers, the other is the Virtual Key Code. Is there a way to get the HotKey ID?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387176.aspx  Actually has THREE parameters, not two. The first of which is the ID you're looking for.

Comment: Get Brandon's happy version by using ON_WM_HOTKEY instead of ON_MESSAGE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this in message map:

```
ON_WM_HOTKEY()
```

And this MFC function:

```
afx_msg void OnHotKey(
    UINT nHotKeyId, 
    UINT nKey1, 
    UINT nKey2
);
```

See also [CWnd::OnHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387176.aspx)

Make sure you remove `ON_MESSAGE(WM_HOTKEY, OnHotKey)` and the other `OnHotKey` declaration and definition.